# C Concatenate string in while loop

Tags: c, string, loops, while-loop, printf

I'm trying to concatenate part of a struct with hex values. I run over every byte in the loop and convert to hex, then I want to concatenate all the hex into one long string.

However, I only end up with one value at the end of the loop. For some reason the string isnt concatenating properly. Any idea what Im doing wrong?

```
typedef struct OPTIONS_STR
{
    int max;
    int printName;
} OPTIONS;

void set_default_options(OPTIONS *options)
{
    options->max = -1;
    options->printName = 0;
}

void do_file(FILE *in, FILE *out, OPTIONS *options)
{
    char ch;
    int loop = 0;
    char buf[81];
    buf[0] = '\0';
    int sz1;
    int sz2;
    int sz3;

    int seeker = offsetof(struct myStruct, contents.datas);

    //find total length of file
    fseek(in, 0L, SEEK_END);
    sz1 = ftell(in);

    //find length from beggining to struct beginning and minus that from total length
    fseek(in, seeker, SEEK_SET);
    sz2 = sz1 - ftell(in);

    //set seek location at beginning of struct offset
    fseek(in, seeker, SEEK_SET);

    sz3 = sz2 + 1;
    char buffer[sz3];
    char msg[sz3];

    buffer[0] = '\0';

    while (loop < sz2)
    {
        if (loop == sz2)
        {
            break;
        }

        fread(&ch, 1, 1, in);
        sprintf(msg, "%02X", (ch & 0x00FF));
        strcpy(buffer, msg);

        ++loop;
    }
    printf("%s\n", buffer);
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    OPTIONS options;
    set_default_options(&options);

    const char *current = "/myfile.txt";
    FILE *f = fopen(current, "rb");
    do_file(f, stdout, &options);
    fclose(f);

};
```

Comment: `strcpy()` copies the source string to the destination string, overwriting its previous contents.  You perhaps want `strcat()`, instead.

Comment: `int index=0; index += sprintf(&buffer[index], "%02X", (ch & 0x00FF));`

Comment: Note, too, that you are not making your buffer large enough.  Each input character requires two hex digits in your buffer, but you make only enough space for one.

Comment: Hi John Bollinger, thanks for confirming this, I thought this was an issue. I still wonder if I have to double the null terminator count as well.

Comment: Hi LPs, how can I print this in hex if it is an int? int index=0; index += sprintf(&buffer[index], "%02X", (ch & 0x00FF));

Comment: Sorry, I'm not getting you. The `sprintf` is inserting HEX values into buffer. Side note: add a @ char to user nickname to allow SO to worn that user about your message.

Comment: Note that offsetof is not a good way to determine an offset in your file. It means your files are not portable across different systems, because that offsetof could vary between those. Better decide for a fixed known offset (i.e. a file format).

Comment: Hi Daniel, in this case, the offsetof is looking for the beginning of the struct, so it should find that on any system? I'm not saving the file, I'm gathering data from it, so the offsetof should be able to get that data on all systems?

Comment: `offsetof(struct myStruct, contents.datas);` gives the offset of the specified member in the struct. The layout of a struct may vary due to different alignment requirements and type sizes. Thus on one platform this could be (say) 4, whereas on another it could be 8.

Comment: The data extracted will still always be the same, because it's looking for that specific struct and only selecting that section. The file I'm reading is from a specific standard, so it's always in the same format. I only need to get the data, which I can get on all the systems Ive tested so far. Are you saying there is still going to be problems with this? If so, I would be interested to find out how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `strcat` instead of `strcpy`. That should fix your problem.

For efficiency look into using a write pointer like `char *p = buffer` and advance the write position with something like `p += sprintf(p, "%02X", (ch & 0x00FF))`

Also your `if(loop == sz2) break` check is a useless duplicate of the `while(loop < sz2)` check. The while loop won't execute if `loop` is equal or bigger than `sz2`.

Also wondering why you use `fread` when you only want one character. `fgetc` or `getc` seems to be a better choice.

Also, no matter if you use `fread` or `getc` you need to check for the end of file. What if the file does *not* have `sz2` bytes in it? Because all modern systems are multiprocess and multiuser, so someone might cut the file short after the call to `ftell`. You should never assume things because even if you just checked it, it can change. Making that assumption is what causes TOCTTOU (Time of Check To Time Of Use) bugs.

Comment: Hi Zan, understood, all of it, apart from the pointer part. How would I include that in my code? Do I declare char *p at the top, when buffer gets created?

Comment: @Ke. It has to come after buffer is created, so it has something to point to. And it cannot be inside the loop or it would get reset to buffer on each loop.

Comment: ok I think I get the pointer thing now, and how sprintf works, so thanks for that, now I'm trying to add some extra characters to the array "\n\t\t\t\t" and it doesnt seem to be working, any idea why?

Comment: @Ke. It sounds to me as if you need to learn to use a debugger. You should have all the tools available to you to make this work.

Comment: @Ke. Also the way you ask that question is impossible for me to answer. You left out all the important details.

Answer (score -1):

In `do_file()`, you are copying the hex value for a single byte in a while loop. Thus, you should go to the next byte of character array `buffer` with each iteration of the while loop i.e. `buffer++` or `strcpy(buffer[loop], msg);`