# C Concatenate string in while loop

Tags: c, string, concatenation, strcat

I cant seem to use the following function to concatenate a string in the while loop. Any idea what Im doing wrong?

```
void do_file(FILE *in, FILE *out, OPTIONS *options)
{
    char ch;
    int loop = 0;
    int sz1,sz2,sz3;

    int seeker = offsetof(struct myStruct, contents.datas);

    //find total length of file
    fseek(in, 0L, SEEK_END);
    sz1 = ftell(in);

    //find length to struct beginning and minus that from total length
    fseek(in, seeker, SEEK_SET);
    sz2 = sz1 - ftell(in);

    sz3 = (sz2 + 1) * 2;//Allocate enough size for 2x array length
    char buffer[sz3];//set size of buffer to be copied to
    char msg[sz3];//set size of msg

    buffer[0] = '\0';

    while (loop < sz2)
    {
        if (loop == sz2)
        {
            break;
        }

        fread(&ch, 1, 1, in);
        //sprintf(msg, "%02X", (ch & 0x00FF));
        strcat(buffer, msg);

        ++loop;
    }
    printf("%s\n", buffer);
}
```

Comment: why do you fseek(in, seeker, SEEK_SET) twice?

Comment: [Repeating the post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39463073/c-concatenate-string-in-while-loop) continuously with little (and wrong/bad) modification is not the way to solve your problems...

Comment: kfsone - good point, I will remove that

Answer (score 0):

Your only `strcat` appends the `char msg[sz3];` which is never filled.

**EDIT**
The simplest fix would be to add

```
msg[1] = '\0';
```

after

```
char msg[sz3];//set size of msg
```

and to replace

```
fread(&ch, 1, 1, in);
```

with

```
fread(&msg[0], 1, 1, in);
```

Comment: Hi GMichael, I'm wondering how do I fill it. I know it probably sounds silly, but I've been trying to fill it for a long time and still cant figure it out, maybe you can help me?

Comment: @Ke. Comparing this to your older question...did you completely forget that you commented out your sprintf line that writes into msg?

Comment: I'm not really sure how that sprintf is supposed to work. I was commenting it out because I thought it was printing into the window for each loop, whereas I wanted it to print one loop at the end. Is the sprintf not really printing into the console then until the end?

Comment: [printf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) and [sprintf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sprintf) don't differ only by a `s` but work differently. As told you many times: look at the man!

Comment: @Ke Please see the update in the answer